# How to override Constant of a gem? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, overriding

I'm working with [Twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb)  gem on my project, but I'm getting some *errors*. I need override one constant of that gem.

I see some questions on StackOverflow about method override that helped me, but I'm still having troubles. I created a file called `twitter-text.rb` in `/config/initializers/` and wrote the following code:

```
module Twitter
  class Regex
    HASHTAG_CHARACTERS = "/[[^ ]_#{LATIN_ACCENTS}]/io"
  end
end
```

(this Regex allows me to write Hashtags with any characters except blank spaces).

I'm trying to override a method too, but it appears that doesn't work too. Following my code (on the same file):

```
module Twitter
  module Autolink
    def auto_link_hashtags(text, options = {})  # :yields: hashtag_text
      text = text.downcase
      options = options.dup
      (...)
    end
  end
end
```

I just added the following line to this method: `text = text.downcase`. Well, what can I do to override this method and attribute/constant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try removing the constant first, then redefining it:

```
module Twitter
  class Regex
    remove_const(:HASHTAG_CHARACTERS) if (defined?(HASHTAG_CHARACTERS))

    HASHTAG_CHARACTERS = "/[[^ ]_#{LATIN_ACCENTS}]/io"
  end
end
```

This is super-ugly [monkeypatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) territory, though.

Comment: Hello @tadman, thanks for your answer! Well, I used what you said, but it still the same. I changed the regex for: HASHTAG_CHARACTERS = "/[[^ ]_#{LATIN_ACCENTS}]/io" to see if the change modified something, but is the same as before. And do you know what can I do for methods?

Comment: Are you sure your fix was applied? You should test what `Twitter::Regex::HASHTAG_CHARACTERS` is set to.

Comment: If you can load up `rails console`, you can always test interactively.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, it's worked for me. Your code successfully override my constant. But I don't know if the method worked too. How can I see if my method was changed?

Comment: You can always check which version of a method you're using with the `source_location` method of Ruby 1.9 or better: `Twitter::Regex.method(:auto_link_hashtags).source_location`

Comment: I got the following message:  ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-text-1.6.1/lib/twitter-text/autolink.rb", 139]. Well, I think this isn't working, because the path for my method is initialize/twitter-text.rb, no?

Comment: That should be in `config/initializers/twitter-text.rb` and it would load after your stack is ready.

Comment: So...what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Is that where it's located? You can always put some debugging code in that patch, something like `puts "I LOADED"` and see if that shows up when you run `rails console`.